# Only see background in bootstrap wells with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap page with wells. The wells should have an image as a background. But the image shouldn't start over for every well. It should be under the whole page. So under the first well you see the first part of the image and under the second well you should see another part of the image a bit lower.

I tried putting everything in a div with that background and making the wells background transparent but that did not work. How would you do this?

This is what it should be, only here the images start over for every well.

```css
.well {
    background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/49/6b/65/496b65edfa8065b1e938dcf25287d9d0.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      
    <h1>page</h1>
    <div class="well">hello</div>
    <div class="well">bye</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work for every number of wells. So when you add a third you should get again a little bit more of the full image. When there are more wells then images is large it can repeat.

Comment: How did you make the well background transparent?

Comment: .well {background: transparent;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one more solution. The background image has to be `cover` and `fixed`:

```css
body {padding:20px}

.container { 
background: gray;
}
.well {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-4.jpg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <h1>page</h1>
    <div class="well">hello</div>
    <div class="well">bye</div>
    <div class="well">hello</div>
    <div class="well">bye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... This is cool... This is not one more solution. **This is the solution!**

Comment: Well, my plan was to have it scroll up with my page, but this looks equally good. (unintentional use of well in this sentence)