# Fill parent container background equally with different size text

Tags: html, css

How can I get the container backgrounds to equally fill their heights on different lengths of text for each grid item in the column?

SCSS:

```
.use-case-block-container{
  margin: 15px;
}
.use-case-block{
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="row">
      <hr>
      <h2>Use Cases</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">CUSTOMER EXPOSURE</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">CUSTOMER ACTIVITY HISTORY</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">CUSTOMER DATA GOVERNANCE</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">DATA LINEAGE</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">AUTOMATED ACCESS OF UNSTRUCTURED DATA</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">REGULATORY COMPLIANCE – SIFI</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">REGULATORY COMPLIANCE – CCAR</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">REGULATORY COMPLIANCE – POST TRADE COMMUNICATIONS</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">PII DATA IDENTIFICATION AND LOCATION</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 ">
                <div class="use-case-block-container">
                  <div class="use-case-block">
                  <a href="/use_cases">COMPREHENSIVE DATA REPAIR</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Result:

[image]

The issue is that the each row of items should have the same block padding on each side. For example, if one of the items had 3 lines instead of 2, each of the blocks should adjust to be 3 lines height instead of 2 or 1. This way all of the containers are the same size and responsive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41445525/4206079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set an appropriate fixed height for all the `.use-case-block-container`'s and use media queries breakpoints to adjust fixed heights when text height changes.

Each `.use-case-block-container`'s can also have `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` for vertical and horizontal centering of text.

Answer (score 0):

You could always loop over them in `js`, find the biggest one and assign that height to all others.

However, I think it's easier to just set some reasonable `min-height` defaults in `css`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don`t want to use JS, you can use flexbox equal column heights:

column containers would be:

display: flex;

do a quick seach for flexbox equal column heights.